# How to divide a number into 1-byte chunks to be sent through serial Bluetooth in C++?

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth, binary, byte

I want to send a number through serial Bluetooth from an Arduino to an Android application.

I've managed to send 1 byte using the following code in C++:

```
int number = 255;          
SerialBT.write((uint8_t*)&number,1);
SerialBT.flush();
```

This works fine, but since Arduino won't admit int16 or any other pointer bigger than 1 byte, I need to "chunk" the number down to 8-bit parts, and send each "chunk" at a time.

For example: if I need to send the number "725", which is 10 1101 0101 in binary, I would need to send 2 bytes:

[image: Example division of binary 725 into two bytes]

How can I divide a number into "8 bit chunks"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```cpp
uint16_t number = 1000;
uint8_t lByte = number & 0b11111111;
uint8_t hByte = number >> 8;
```

There are also `lowByte()` and `highByte()` functions available, but I don't know their exact behaviour.

But why not use `SerialBT.print()` or `SerialBT.println()` and convert what you receive into a number?

Comment: That worked excellent!
The actual number is data obtained from load cells, but you approach worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Alejandro-Monsalve-Krause: Good! Don't forget to accept the answer so the question doesn't stay open.